Forward Visual Mode Selection in Neovim to Telescope's Live-Grep-Args via Register
Background:
Currently, I am forwarding a selection to Telescope's Live-Grep-Args plugin via a register by using the following code:
...
-- Forward Visual Selection to Live-Grep-Args --
local function grep_visual_selection()

    -- Yank the current visual selection into to register "a"  
    vim.cmd('normal! "ay')  
  
    -- Get the content of register "a" and escape spaces  
    local visual_selection = vim.fn.escape(vim.fn.getreg('a'), ' ')  

    -- Call Telescope live_grep with the escaped visual selection  
    vim.cmd('Telescope live_grep default_text=' .. visual_selection)  
end 

...

keymap('v', '<leader>fs', grep_visual_selection, { noremap = true, silent = true })


While this works, I am wondering myself why the unnamed register is also modified in parallel to the register "a". This behaviour also persists when yanking manually a selection to a specific register (in this case register "a"). I would have expected only the register "a" to be modified. Because of this behaviour, the following questions came up to my mind
Questions

Does yanking in vim/nvim always modify the unnamed register? (Even when depositing a selection in a special register)
Are there any approaches which do not modify the unnamed register?


From :help quote-quote: "Vim fills this register with text deleted with the "d", "c", "s", "x" commands or copied with the yank "y" command, regardless of whether or not a specific register was used (e.g.  "xdd)."

Ahh I see, reading the doc would have been helpful. Ok thanks @romainl
